# difference between weak and strong topologiccal insulators

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

Does someone know what the difference is between weak and strong topological insulators? (And do both exist in any dimension?).

Comment: You are encourage to do a literature survey here: http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.106803